# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in - api platform and symfony 6

Tags: docker, symfony, api-platform.com

I am running a docker project with symfony 6 and PHP 8 and I am getting the error:

> "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
> file or directory in . (which is being imported from
> "/app/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader
> supporting the "api_platform" type."

I'm trying to display GET request with api platform.

From this error I thought it might be the database connexion (mariadb database) but I checked and it was fine.

in my .env:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@localhost:3307/databasetest"
```

the url of the symfony server with the swagger of api platform:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
```

I thought it was because the entity I used still had annotations instead of attribute despite being in symfony 6 so I used rector package to upgrade my entity file with attribute. I also added getter et setter to all properties.

I don't understand why the error is pointing toward api platform in the message?

I did run a similar project without docker and with a SQL database and it worked fine.
I had this in its .env:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/databasetest?serverVersion=8&charset=utf8mb4"
```

I tried adding the version at the end but that's not it:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@localhost:3307/databasetest?serverVersion=10&charset=utf8mb4"
```

(at least the DATABASE_URL with the version added, displays http://127.0.0.1:8000/api, but the error "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" is still present)
Any advice please?

---

edit: I thought I had the solution which is:

> I am not sure when or why the problem was solved because I have tried
> several things in between but using the service name for the
> DATABASE_URL:
>
> DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@database:3306/databasetest" or
> DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@database:3306/databasetest?serverVersion=10&charset=utf8"
>
> and it works... I tried this at the beginning I think? So I'm not sure
> if the changes I tried really made it work
>
> Thanks @Hans Kilian for pointing again the service name docker-compose
>
> - PHP instance seems not to communicate with db service

but no because I need to use:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@database:3306/databasetest"
```

if I want to use api platform, but I need to use:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@localhost:3307/databasetest"
```

if I want to change my data in the database, or use symfony commands such as "php bin/console make:migration" which result in error ""An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" when doing API request on api platform

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  database:
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
```

So my final problem is to find out a DATABASE_URL which make both the api platform work and symfony commands work, if someone have any advise...

Comment: if you are using docker then I will suggest to see networks settings 
if both db and application are at same network or can communicate with each other
I also face that kind of issue too and result is messing with networks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add a container_name to your database service, so you will be able to call it as a network in your .env file:

```yaml
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    container_name: "my_database"
    ...
    ...
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

then replace localhost by the container name in your .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin@my_database:3307/databasetest"
```

Be aware that I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works fine for development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by removing this line

```
services:
  php:
    # I passed an env file ... for no reason ^^' 
    env_file:
      - app/.env
```

from my `compose.yml` file but I'm still not sure what was the problem behind that ... But it definitely created an error between my php and my database services, the socket was not usable ...